# Add new row(s) dynamically in empty table using telerik grid in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I'm just starting to use the ASP.NET MVC.

i am thinking of adding an "Add New Row" button to the top to add a new data row to the table/grid in a form.

Initially, I want the grid/table to be empty, with only headers of table to be displayed. however, if there are no data rows, the whole grid doesn't appear.

Is there any why by which I can do display empty table and can add new rows dynamically.

And at end of page I want "Submit" button by clicking on that button  all the rows which I have added using "Add New Row" in the table will be added in database.

I also need option to Edit , delete each row before submitting.

Please suggest me the way to perform the above operation.

Answer (score 1):

Up to your questions:

1. The grid should display empty even if there is no data. I am not sure what went wrong. You can paste some code.
2. Batch editing is not currently supported. You can insert or edit one row at a time.